# react-router-dom match object isExact false

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am working on a react project. I try to access the url parameters in the Header component. However, it always returns empty.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import SamplePage from './pages/SamplePage';
import PropertyPage from './pages/PropertyPage';
import LoadingPage from './pages/LoadingPage';
import Header from './header/Header';
import ButtonGroup from './ButtonGroup';
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import history from '../history';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/loading' exact component={LoadingPage} />
          <Route component={Header} title='Sample page' />
        </Switch>
        <Container style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path='/page/:pageType/properties/:propertyId'
              exact
              component={PropertyPage}
            />
            <Route path='/page/:pageType' exact component={SamplePage} />
          </Switch>
        </Container>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/loading' render={() => <div />} />
          <Route component={ButtonGroup} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I try to access url params in the Header component. The params is empty, and isExact is false.  Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you on a url matching path `/scorecard/:scorecardType/properties/:propertyId`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule. Yes, I am. You can see that my pathname under location object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still cannot figure out how to solve this issue. What I do to walk around this issue is to create a Higher Order Component. Header will be included in the HOC, then it has no problem to get the URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

From screenshot of `console.log`, `react-router` is matching on

```
<Route component={Header} title='Sample Scorecard' />
```

This is correct behavior as `Switch` looks for the first match.

I suggest to not declare rendering for `Header` as a `Route`. i.e.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/loading' exact component={LoadingPage} />
    <Header title='Sample Scorecard' />
</Switch>
```

This way `Switch` will only render it when `loading` path isn't matched.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated it, but it does not affect the match.params. I still get empty.

Comment: The pathname in the `console.log` is `/scorecard/SME`. That should match the route for the sample page.  What is the pathname under the location object

Comment: Yes. The location is correct. But the params under the match object is empty, and match['path'] is '/'.

Comment: I'm not sure why match path is `'/'` if you're on the right location. I have tried to replicate your route setup but nothing jumps at me why you're getting a different result. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-registration-login-example-2mcghy

Comment: If my console.log is under SamplePage.js, everything is also good. This only happens when I use it under the Header component.